# Reseting Privacy and Security -> Input Monitoring setting

Tags: macos, settings, privacy

To remove my application from the Accessibility pane I do this in terminal:

```
sudo tccutil reset InputM appsidentifier
```

Which successfully removes the app from the Accessibility pane but when I try the same for InputMonitoring it does not works.

```
sudo tccutil reset ScreenCapture appsidentifier
```

I get this:

```
Failed to reset InputMonitoring approval status for appIdentifier
```

After a lot of research I’m unable to find anything on it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like you mixed the permission service names while posting? First command would be `... Accessibility ...`, second `... InputMonitoring ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean: `sudo tccutil reset InputMonitoring appsidentifier`

I happened to find [this article](https://recoursive.com/2020/03/03/reset_macos_privacy_permissions/) which lists all the entries that `tccutil` accepts. `InputMonitoring` isn't among the list, but `ListenEvent` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It is effective for me

reseting input monitor

```
tccutil reset ListenEvent appsidentifier
```

reseting input accessibility

```
tccutil reset Accessibility appsidentifier
```